# Is it a reasonable approach for lock-free design for this scenario

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, locking, task-parallel-library, async-await

This is kind of follow up to one of my earlier question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27881854/can-i-design-any-lock-free-solution-for-this-scenario). In summary I am trying to come up with a lock free design for this scenario where I upon cancellation of task I want to call a method of third party library. In response to my question, a helpful SO participant suggested to use CancellationToken.Register but I am not sure where and how can I use that here. Below is code that I come up with. Please let me know if you see any issue with this approach or if there are any better alternatives to solve this problem.

```
class ProcessEmployees
    {
        private List<Employee> _Employees;
        CancellationTokenSource cs = new CancellationTokenSource();

        public  ProcessEmployees()
        {
            _Employees = new List<Employee>() 
            {
                new Employee() { ID = 1, FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" },
                new Employee() { ID = 2, FirstName = "Peter", LastName = "Saul" },
                new Employee() { ID = 3, FirstName = "Mike", LastName = "Sue" },
                new Employee() { ID = 4, FirstName = "Catherina", LastName = "Desoza" },
                new Employee() { ID = 5, FirstName = "Paul", LastName = "Smith" }
            };
        }

        public void StartProcessing()
        {
            try
            {
                Task[] tasks = this._Employees.AsParallel().WithCancellation(cs.Token).Select(x => this.ProcessThisEmployee(x, cs.Token)).ToArray();
                Task.WaitAll(tasks);
            }
            catch (AggregateException ae)
            {
                // error handling code
            }
            // other stuff
        }

        private async Task ProcessThisEmployee(Employee x, CancellationToken token)
        {
            ThirdPartyLibrary library = new ThirdPartyLibrary();
            if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => library.SomeAPI(x) );
            if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                library.Clean();
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why would you check for cancellation _after_ the operation has completed? Assuming the bulk of the processing time is spend in the `SomeAPI()` method, what's the point of checking for cancellation in the `ProcessThisEmployee()` method at all? What _specific_ advice beyond that which you can find at e.g. [How to: Cancel a PLINQ Query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd460707(v=vs.100).aspx) is it that you seek?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your process code can be simplified to the following (here is how you use Register)

```
private void ProcessThisEmployee(Employee x, CancellationToken token)
{
    ThirdPartyLibrary library = new ThirdPartyLibrary();
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    using(token.Register(() => library.Clean())
    {
        library.SomeAPI(x);
    }
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); //Not sure why you cancel here in your original example.
}
```

If the token is canceled while within the scope of the `using` statement it will call `library.Clean()` if it is called afterwards it does not call the function. I also got rid of your `Task.Run`, there is no reason to waste the extra thread for what you are doing. Lastly I got rid of the extra `if (token.IsCancellationRequested)` checks, `ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` has that if check inside of itself, you don't need to check beforehand.

Also, because in my simplification you are not returning tasks anymore your StartProcessing code becomes

```
    public void StartProcessing()
    {
        try
        {
            this._Employees.AsParallel().WithCancellation(cs.Token).ForAll(x => this.ProcessThisEmployee(x, cs.Token));
        }
        catch (AggregateException ae)
        {
            // error handling code
        }
        // other stuff
    }
```

using `ForAll(` instead of `Select(`

Comment: Thanks. One question. Let's say I want to include WithDegreeOfParallelism in my query expression also with a capacity of 2. Given that I have 5 items in the List and let's say token cancelled while the first 2 operations are in process. In this case, the last 3 items will not be attempted at all or do I need to have something extra in this query expression or code?

Comment: The WithCancellation will make it not even start the last 3. That is what that modifier does, it does not effect items that already started (which is why you have to put your own cancel code in

Comment: one thing I missed to ask that now you don't have await on call to library.SomeAPI so this will become a blocking call. Any particular reason why you removed that?

Comment: It was a blocking call before too (kinda). You where already on a threadpool thread from the `AsParallel` call so there is no reason to create the extra threadpool thread via the `Task.Run` call. Also you did the blocking call `Task.WaitAll(tasks)` in your start method causing the code to block there, I just made the code block one line earlier. Had you used `await Task.WhenAll(tasks)` in your original program I would not have changed the behavior.

Comment: I see. Thanks for taking time explaining it